# Solving $y''=\frac{1}{2}(y^3-y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve $$y''=\frac{1}{2}(y^3-y)$$

I tried normal second order techniques, but they lead to a dead end. How can I tackle this?

Thanks.

Comment: $$2y''\cdot y'=(y^3-y)y'$$

Integrating 
$$(y')^2=\frac{y^4-2y^2+c}4$$

$$\implies 2y'=\pm\sqrt{(y^2-1)^2+c-1}$$

Comment: Ah yes, I see! But how do I now integrate that?

Comment: The polynomial under the root sign is of degree four, so it's going to be an elliptic integral.

Comment: @HansLundmark. Your are right but I bet that the result could be a real nightmare to handle just to get $x(y)$ !!

Comment: Of course, but unfortunately that's the way things usually are with equations of this type...

Comment: Hi Claude !  Sure, a nightmare in the general case. But if Levi specifies the boundary conditions it should be possible (if by chance $c=1$) that the nightmare decomes a pleasant dream !

Answer (score 0):

From $ y'' y' = \frac{1}{2} y^3 y' - \frac{1}{2} y y' $ we have
$ y'^2 = \frac{1}{8} y^4 - \frac{1}{4} y^2 + C$ hence $y$ can be written in terms of the [Jacobi elliptic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) $\operatorname{sn}\left(u,k\right)$.